# Find all records that match a pattern in collection

Tags: c#, regex

I have been banging my head on this one.  I need to extract all records from a collection where a field contains "[" + Any  Number + "]".  Basically [0], [1], [2], etc.  If it has a number enclosed in brackets, I need it.  I tried:

```
allvalues.Where(p => p.Path.Contains(property.Path) && p.Path.Contains(p.Path.Split('[', ']')[1])
```

But if it does not exist, I get the the dreaded error

> Index out of bounds

I cannot use the following:

```
allvalues.Where(p => p.Path.Contains(property.Path) && p.Path.Contains('[')
```

because there are some paths that contain "[]" and I don't want those.

I thought about Regex.IsMatch, but since I was unable to find any such examples, I assume that you cannot mix it with the lambda.

Comment: Are you needing to validate the pattern `[#]` or can `[#[`,  `]#]`, `]#[` be valid matches as well?

Comment: @MatthewWhited  I just needed to include a number between brackets.  The number itself was not important in this particular instance.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: correct, but what if the brackets don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right about regular expressions, they seem like a good fit here.

Use pattern `\[\d+\]`

Explanation:

`\[` - match `[` ltierally

`\d+` - match one ore more digtis

`\]` - match `]` literally

Usage in code:

```
allvalues
  .Where(p => p.Path.Contains(property.Path) && Regex.Match(p.Path, @"\[\d+\]").Success);
```

Comment: This looks promising, but p.Path is not an exact match for [0] it just contains it.  Is there a way to use that Regex with .Contains?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Well if it contains such pattern, it will match it, so it will work as deisred.